# Mashape API objective-C boilerplate code giving errors

Tags: xcode, json, mashape

I am trying to use an API From Mashape.
When I test the endpoint (JSON response), things are working well, 
but the objective-c app-ready code example they give is not working, I get the following errors:

[image: Code Errors]

This is my code:

```
- (IBAction)loadJson:(id)sender
{
    NSDictionary* headers = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"xxxxxxxxx", @"X-Mashape-Authorization", nil];
    NSDictionary* parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSURL URLWithString:@"<file url>"], @"files", @"", @"urls", nil];

    HttpJsonResponse* response = [[Unirest post:^(BodyRequest* request) {
        [request setUrl:@"https://lambda-face-recognition.p.mashape.com/detect"];
        [request setHeaders:headers];
        [request setParameters:parameters];
    }] asJson];
}
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [code examples](https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-obj-c) show this is actually what the code should look like:

```
NSDictionary* headers = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"application/json", @"accept", nil];
NSDictionary* parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value", @"parameter", @"bar", @"foo", nil];

HttpJsonResponse* response = [[Unirest postEntity:^(BodyRequest* request) {
  [request setUrl:@"http://httpbin.org/post"];
  [request setHeaders:headers];
  // Converting NSDictionary to JSON:
  [request setBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:headers options:0 error:nil]];
}] asJson];
```

Or, maybe this one:

```
NSDictionary* headers = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"application/json", @"accept", nil];
NSURL file = nil;
NSDictionary* parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value", @"parameter", file, @"file", nil];

HttpJsonResponse* response = [[Unirest post:^(MultipartRequest* request) {
  [request setUrl:@"http://httpbin.org/post"];
  [request setHeaders:headers];
  [request setParameters:parameters];
}] asJson];
```